# Do special functions get called every time I create an object?

Tags: python, class, magic-methods

Just like the `__init__()` method, do the other special functions get called automatically when I create an object?

Check out this simple class for example:

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x = 0, y = 0):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    
    def __str__(self):
        return "({0},{1})".format(self.x,self.y)
```

Is the `__str__()` method called automatically when I create a new object?

Answer (score 2):

No. Magic/special methods are only get called when their time arrives. When you create an instance of your class, your initializer method (`__init__`) is get called. when you print your object using `print` or when you call `str()` function, the `__str__` method gets called. So this is in `print()` line, not when you create an instance of your class.

Put a simple print statement inside your methods, and run your script in interactive mode to see when which method is gets called.

In interactive mode, if you don't use `print` function, you will see that `__str__` will not get called. Instead `__repr__` is called. since you havn't implement that in your class, you will inherit it from the `object` class.

```py
>>> obj = Point()
>>> print(obj)
(0,0)
>>> obj
<__main__.Point object at 0x0000024E0989D940>
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

At each time you create an object, the `__init__` method is called.

At each time you print an object, the `__str__` method is called to get.

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x = 0, y = 0):
        print('__init__')
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    
    def __str__(self):
        print('__str__')
        return "({0},{1})".format(self.x,self.y)
```

```
>>> p = Point(3, 2)
__init__

>>> print(p)
__str__
(3,2)

>>> p
<__main__.Point at 0x7fa3ab341940>
```

For the last case, the `__str__` method is not called but `__repr__`. A good practice is to override this method to create a string representation of the creation of the instance like `Point(3, 2)`:

```
    def __repr__(self):
        print('__repr__')
        return f"Point({self.x}, {self.y})"
```

```
>>> p = Point(4, 6)
__init__

>>> p
__repr__
Point(4, 6)
```